# How do I change the git repo but keep the files?

Tags: git, github

I cloned a project from someone on GitHub and made changes to it. Later I realized these changes wouldn't just be helpful to me but also to others, so I wanted to make a pull request. In order to do that I need to have my own public version of it that the maintainer of the original can accept my pull-request from.

I host my projects on github, so I made a repo by forking it. But now I want to apply my local commits (using the git file of the original) to my own version. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git remote set-url origin [url]`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the original repo as an `upstream` remote:

```
$ git remote rename origin upstream
```

Then add your GitHub repo as the original:

```
$ git remote add origin [url-of-your-github-repo]
```

Then you can periodically pull in changes from that repo:

```
$ git pull upstream
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add your repo as a remote, push to it, and send the pull request.

```
git remote add mine $YOUR_REPO_CLONE_URL
git push mine $NAME_OF_YOUR_BRANCH
```

And send the pr.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check this link ?
Should be able to solve the issue.
http://gbayer.com/development/moving-files-from-one-git-repository-to-another-preserving-history/